# Facebook Audience Network - Failed to load

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-audience-network

I'm using Facebook Audience Network in my app to display ads.
Sometimes, when I load an ad I get an error message :

```
Facebook - Interstitial ad is failed to load with error: Error Domain=com.facebook.ads.sdk Code=1001 "No fill" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No fill, FBAdErrorDetailKey={
msg = "No fill";
}}
```

About this error, Facebok say : "You can fallback to another ad network in this case, but do not re-request an ad immediately after."

Ok I agree. The problem is to know when do have to try again to load an ad. I retry to load 10 seconds after but the problem is that I do tons of request. So in my Facebook Audience Network dashboard I get a really bad and low Fill Rate (around 9%).

What's the best practice to restart loading an ad.

I've a manager that try to load an ad in the init. Then, each time a user show an ad, after that I reload an ad. Then as I said If I get an error message I reload an ad 10 seconds after.

I need to know what are the best practices and if someone has a better idea than load it every 10 seconds if there is an error.

Comment: Why would you reload every 10 seconds?

Comment: Cause I want to have as much as possible an ad ready to show.

Comment: But if there was no ad to show why do you think there is an ad to show 10 seconds later?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know when an ad will be ready to get it. So I check every 10 seconds until I get an ad

Comment: So then it is expected that you have a low fill rate